# React SPA (Router) create 3d animations (flip/rolling) to switch between components

Tags: reactjs, animation

I want to create animation between my two react components - its known thing, it took me 2 minutes to google that, but my target is to make 3D flip/roll animation (imagine cuboid, and 4 pages on cuboid walls, and transitions between those pages) between routes in SPA.

Do you know some library that can handle that? I haven't found anything on my research.

Answer (score 0):

`react-spring` and `react-router` should be able to accomplish what you're asking for.

In short, what you do is use the `__RouterContext` from `react-router-dom` to retrieve the location and use `react-spring`'s `useTransition` to map over it, and place your `Switch` and all of your `Route`s inside of an `animated.div`.

Check out this tutorial: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=8s2S8lgrJys&t=922s (produced on 26 Apr 2019).

Comment: I mean... I saw this tutorial even before asking question, but i didn't carefully watched this video, just skipped to result - and it isn't 3D. I will check out documentations libraries that you provided. Howevery maybe I didn't wrote my question that clear - I compared my target webpage to cuboid, 3D object where every "subpage" (SPA naming is a bit different than in static page) is one wall of cuboid. I didn't mean 2D object, 2D rectangle where every subpage is just piece of those 2D space.

Comment: @DolidodTeethtard At ~8:49 you can see where he defines the transforms. Instead of applying a 2D `translate()` you could use a `translate3d()` instead. Please read more about this here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform-function/translate3d. `react-spring` provides you the tools to perform pretty much any animation imaginable, but you just need to do a little bit of setup to tell it what type of animations, when, and in what order. Using `translate3d` in the `enter` and `leave` params will allow you to have the previous and next pages be different sides of a cube.

Comment: Okey, I will read and then accept your answer. Thanks for documentation link.

Comment: No prob. Just let me know if you need some more examples or anything. `react-spring`'s documentation is pretty robust, but some of the vocabulary it uses is confusing. https://www.react-spring.io/docs/hooks/basics

Comment: I read docs but I am not sure if I understand - i studied this example - https://codesandbox.io/embed/01yl7knw70, its excatly what I need so I studied this code and I know what is going on there. But I don't know how to implement it with links, so if you can, please provide some example.

Comment: I also found this library: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-card-flip, but it doesn't support more than front and back page

Comment: Just plop a function similar to `perspective(600px) rotateX(${flipped ? 180 : 0}deg)` from the example you just sent into the video I sent, instead of the `transform3d` that he uses in the video. The key is using `useTransition` from `react-spring`